# How to save and render emoji from a javascript webapp and backend Apache Derby

Tags: javascript, unicode, derby, emoji

I am submitting an emoji (from my Mac) in my http post request as:

It is saved in my derby database as:
ðŸ˜€

And it is sent back in response as:
ðŸ˜€

I am bit confused as to 1) is my image and char output the same but just using different encoding? 2) my html is using utf-8 tag - so how can I have browser display the emoji image?

More info:
I wrote a JUnit test as below:

```
System.out.println(Charset.defaultCharset()); <-- prints UTF-8
String str = "ðâ½ï¸";   
System.out.println("testConvertToUtf8:"+new String(str.getBytes(UTF_8))); <--- prints char. 
System.out.println("testConvertToUtf8:"+new String(str.getBytes(ISO_8859_1))); <-- displays emojis!!!
```

Why are emoji's showing up when I encode char using ISO_8859_1? I am running on OS El Capitan 10.11.6

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Basically my request encoding was getting changed from utf-8 to iso-8859-1 by Apache ServletFileUpload while reading multipart/form-data. I modified fileItem.getString() to fileItem.getString(charset) as below and that fixed my issue:

```
    ServletFileUpload upload = new ServletFileUpload(factory);
    items = upload.parseRequest(httpServletRequestHelper);
}
for (FileItem item : items) {
    if (item.isFormField()) {
        String charset = item.getContentType() == null ? "UTF-8" : item.getContentType();
            this.setStringAttribute(item.getFieldName(), new String[] { **item.getString(charset)** }, parseHash);
        }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Please set your database's encoding as `utf8mb4`

Comment: I am not seeing utf8mb4 char encoding option in Apache Derby. Per Derby docs: Character data types are represented as Unicode 2.0 sequences in Derby. https://db.apache.org/derby/docs/10.3/devguide/cdevcollation.html

Comment: I created a test table with a varchar(100) column and inserted an emoji (copying from my system and pasting it within an insert statement). That record came back fine with emojis. So my db is capable of handling emojis. Just wanted to post this re Apache Derby - UTF compatibility...